# Speed vector blurring not working

Tags: compositing-nodes, fluid-simulation

Ive got a fluid sim in v2.82.7 and is rendered with Cycles. I am trying to use the 'use speed vectors' in the fluid sim while using the vector blur node but it blurs nothing. I do have the vector pass on; I tried turning odd de-noising in case that was it but to no avail. Its probably something little I'm missing but I cannot find it. The node setup and render are below. I am not sure what other info would be helpful to give.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are two steps need to be confirmed for the correct result:

1. Domain -> Mesh -> Use Speed Vector, make sure it's checked
2. Domain -> Cache -> Format Volumes -> Uni Cache, make sure it's choosen

then you will have a motion blur of fluid.